# Is it possible to make thosunds of concurrent transactions even if the max_connections is set to 100 in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql-9.6, max-connections

This is maybe a dummy queestion but I couldn't understand to have thousands of concurrent transactions in a database even if the `max_connections=100`.

Definition of max_connections from postgres documentation:

> Determines the maximum number of concurrent connections to the database server. The default is typically 100 connections, but might be less if your kernel settings will not support it (as determined during initdb). This parameter can only be set at server start.
>   When running a standby server, you must set this parameter to the same or higher value than on the master server. Otherwise, queries will not be allowed in the standby server.
>   [link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/runtime-config-connection.html)

Some DBA's says that we have 5k instant transactions. But actually max_connections parameters is much less than that. (300 for example)

Is there any explanation?

Comment: Do they mean that you have 5k concurrent transactions though? Or 5K transactions per second? I've never heard of the term "N instant transactions" used by the way.

Comment: I understand as concurrent transactions. Actually I want to know if it is possible to have 5k concurrent transactions or DBA's mean transactions per second with the word "instant"?

Comment: You will have to ask them what they mean. The common term is "tps" eg. 5k tps (transactions per second). I do not think you can have more than 300 concurrent transaction if your max_connections is set to 300.

Comment: Ypercube is right: each connection can at most have one "active" transaction. So you can never have more concurrent (=active) transactions that your maximum amount of connections. I would also guess that your DBA refers to transactions per second. 5K tps is nothing to be worried about though. Good hardware can sustain a lot more than that